# Hair particles does not update the length

Tags: particles, hair

[image]
Blender 2.93.0 The simple scene: sphere with the collision on it, hair particle system with a hair dynamics tuned on, and a wind force field. I can not change the length of the hair for some reason (it just doesn't react). Also, the hair dynamics setting just disappear sometimes (with the checkbox still active) so I have to turn it off and on to make it work again. Is it a bug or some extra steps should be done to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the first one: Wind somehow affects the length of the hair. Turned off the wind and the length can be changed now. Notice that you have to be on frame 1 to see the changes